# How to add a user in Active Directory with name longer than 20 characters?

Tags: active-directory, ad-lds

I am using Windows 2008 R2 Server and trying to add a user in Active Directory.

I am able to save user ID of length less than 20 characters. But when I try to increase this value to 30 characters I get this error:

```
“System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryServicesCOMException (0x8007001F): A device attached to the system is not functioning. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007001F)”
```

This error when I searched on net give me various links  saying that:

- Please verify if the issue is caused by the length of sAMAccountName
- The document of SAM-Account-Name also indicates that the length of it
  should be less than 20 characters.

I am using the code below to add user in Active Directory

```
public static void AddUser(ADUser adUser)
{
       if (_logger.IsDebugEnabled)
          _logger.Debug("ADHelper.cs: Enter AddUser");


         // Local variables
            DirectoryEntry oDE = null;
            DirectoryEntry oDENewUser = null;
            DirectoryEntries oDEs = null;

try
{
oDE = GetDirectoryEntry(GetADPath(adUser.UserType));

// 1. Create user account
oDEs = oDE.Children;
oDENewUser = oDEs.Add("CN=" + adUser.UserName, "user");

// 2. Set properties
SetProperty(oDENewUser, Constants.ADAttributes.givenName, adUser.FirstName);
SetProperty(oDENewUser, Constants.ADAttributes.initials, adUser.MiddleInitial);
SetProperty(oDENewUser, Constants.ADAttributes.sn, adUser.LastName);
SetProperty(oDENewUser, Constants.ADAttributes.mail, adUser.Email);
SetProperty(oDENewUser, Constants.ADAttributes.sAMAccountName, adUser.UserName);

SetProperty(oDENewUser, Constants.ADAttributes.ChallengeQuestion, adUser.PasswordChallengeQuestion);
SetProperty(oDENewUser, Constants.ADAttributes.ChallengeAnswer, adUser.PasswordChallengeAnswer);

SetProperty(oDENewUser, Constants.ADAttributes.ChallengeQuestion2, adUser.PasswordChallengeQuestion2);
SetProperty(oDENewUser, Constants.ADAttributes.ChallengeAnswer2, adUser.PasswordChallengeAnswer2);

// Sharepoint changes
if (adUser.CompanyGroupSupplier != string.Empty)
{
SetProperty(oDENewUser, Constants.ADAttributes.CompanyGroupSupplier, adUser.CompanyGroupSupplier);
}
if (adUser.PersonalGroupAddress != string.Empty)
{
SetProperty(oDENewUser, Constants.ADAttributes.PersonalGroupAddress, adUser.PersonalGroupAddress);
}
if (adUser.PersonalGroupPhone != string.Empty)
{
SetProperty(oDENewUser, Constants.ADAttributes.PersonalGroupPhone, adUser.PersonalGroupPhone);
}
// Sharepoint changes

oDENewUser.CommitChanges();

// 3. Set password
SetPassword(oDENewUser.Path, adUser.Password);

// 4. Enable account
EnableAccount(oDENewUser);

oDENewUser.Close();
oDE.Close();

if (_logger.IsDebugEnabled)
_logger.Debug("ADHelper.cs: Exit AddUser");

}
catch (ApplicationException appex)
{
if (_logger.IsErrorEnabled)
_logger.Error("ADHelper.cs: Exception occurred in AddUser. Message: ", appex);
throw appex;
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
if (_logger.IsErrorEnabled)
_logger.Error("ADHelper.cs: Exception occurred in AddUser. Message: ", ex);
throw ex;
}
finally
{
if (oDENewUser != null)
{
oDENewUser.Dispose();
oDENewUser = null;
}
if (oDEs != null)
{
oDEs = null;
}
if (oDE != null)
{
oDE.Dispose();
oDE = null;
}
}
}
```

How can I increase sAMAccountName length in Active Directory to around 30 characters in length?

Comment: If this is a real user account, I don't think anyone really wants to be typing in a 20-character username. Mine is 11 and that's annoying enough.

Answer (score 4):

As you've already found and stated in your question, the attribute is limited to 20 characters ([MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms679635.aspx)). This is for backwards compatibility. Active Directory itself is imposing this restriction therefore you can't override it programmatically.

Answer (score 3):

20 characters is the limit for the "Pre-Windows 2000" name, also known as the samAccountName.

Refer to this previous answer for more information:   https://serverfault.com/a/335565/20701